# Run console application without window

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I have 3 console programs (.exe), and I want to run them from one console application without showing the windows of the 3 console programs.
All programs are written in VC++.
Any suggestions about how I can do this?

Comment: `ShellExecute`, `CreateProcess`, `WinExec`, making them not have windows normally...

Comment: This solution may prove useful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16163/Real-Time-Console-Output-Redirection#solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ShellExecute command to run the other application

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the ShellExecute Function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx

SW_HIDE as last parameter will ... well, hide the window.